# The arguments of the array in the COUNTIFS function have different sizes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

```
=IF(OR($B136="",J$5=""),"",
COUNTIFS(
DAY('all'!$C$12:$C),DAY(J$5),
MONTH('all!$C$12:$C),MONTH(J$5),
YEAR('all'!$C$12:$C),YEAR(J$5),
'all'!$X$12:$X,IF($B136="none","",$B136),
'all'!$H$12:$H,$B$135))
```

This formula returns an "array arguments to countif are of different size" error how do I fix it

Comment: Please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet so we can replicate what you have. Remove sensitive data if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can you test this: (now wrapped in `arrayformula()` & one apostrophe missing for `all` at `month` part*

```js
=IF(OR($B136="",J$5=""),"",
arrayformula(
COUNTIFS(
DAY('all'!$C$12:$C),DAY(J$5),
MONTH('all'!$C$12:$C),MONTH(J$5),
YEAR('all'!$C$12:$C),YEAR(J$5),
'all'!$X$12:$X,IF($B136="none","",$B136),
'all'!$H$12:$H,$B$135)))
```